# Distance between predicted interval and datas (stat_smooth)

Tags: r

I used `stat_smooth()` in R for the first time and i want to know if there is a way to get, for each `x`, the distance between the `data(y)` and the predicted interval as you can see on the picture here:

[image]

Thank you for your precious help !

Comment: could you share your data and the code you used to generate the plot using `dput(data)`?

Comment: what to do with those data points which are inside the interval? For those cases: `distance == 0`?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You not asked a proper question (as suggested above). But I also think you're not properly understanding what your question is statistically/programmatically. `stat_smooth` applies one of many smoothers, `stat::loess` by default. What you're asking is about the residual from the loess prediction and the data itself (or, more specifically, a transformation of the prediction --the upper or lower prediction interval). You would not do this via `ggplot2::stat_smooth` but via the smoothing method itself.

Comment: There are many parameters that go into this prediction interval (the method (loess, lm, glm, etc), the confidence level, etc.... I think you need to start simpler. Also, it would be helpful if you elaborated what you are trying to do (ie--why do you want this distance?).

Comment: This is not to discourage you, merely to suggest that you need a better understanding of your problem. And, that if you want help, you need to better communicate what **exactly** you want.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments above, clarification of your goals would be helpful.

If you want to replicate, what `ggplot2` does and find distances for points outside of the interval, I have some code for you.

First I create some sample data and plot it:

```
library(ggplot2)
# sample data
set.seed(1234)
x <- c(1:100)
y <- c(1:100) + rnorm(100, sd = 5)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(alpha = .4) + stat_smooth(span = .3)
```

[image: plot_output]

Then I replicate what `ggplot2` does: I build a loess model (`ggplot2` chooses loess if `n < 1000`), which I subsequently use to build the confidence intervals in the same way `stat_smooth` does. **Note**: Parameters of the model need to match the parameters you used in `stat_smooth`.

```
# find model, matching the span parameter from the graph above
model <- loess(y ~ x, data = df, span = 0.3)

# find x sequence
xseq <- sort(unique(df$x))

# function adapted from ggplot2::predictdf.loess:
# https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/f3b519aa90907f13f5d649ff6a512fd539f18b2b/R/stat-smooth-methods.r#L45
predict_loess <- function(model, xseq, level = 0.95) {
  pred <- stats::predict(model, newdata = data.frame(x = xseq), se = TRUE)

  y_pred = pred$fit
  ci <- pred$se.fit * stats::qt(level / 2 + .5, pred$df)
  ymin = y_pred - ci
  ymax = y_pred + ci

  data.frame(x = xseq, y_pred, ymin, ymax, se = pred$se.fit)
}

# predict your data
predicted_data <- predict_loess(model, xseq, level = 0.95)

# merge predicted data with original y
merged_data <- with(df, cbind(predicted_data, y))

head(merged_data)
#   x     y_pred       ymin     ymax       se         y
# 1 1 -0.5929504 -5.8628535 4.676953 2.652067 -5.035329
# 2 2  0.2828659 -4.1520646 4.717796 2.231869  3.387146
# 3 3  1.1796057 -2.5623056 4.921517 1.883109  8.422206
# 4 4  2.1074914 -1.0994171 5.314400 1.613870 -7.728489
# 5 5  3.0696584  0.2371895 5.902127 1.425434  7.145623
# 6 6  4.0568034  1.4454944 6.668113 1.314136  8.530279
```

From the replicated data we can now find the distances. For cases inside the interval it returns `0`.

```
distances <- with(merged_data, ifelse(y < ymin, ymin - y,
                                      ifelse(y > ymax, y - ymax, 0)))
head(distances)
# [1] 0.000000 0.000000 3.500689 6.629071 1.243496 1.862167
```

It's not a very elegant solution, but it could point you in the right direction.